# Why components cannot be rendered by custom protected react-routers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have several components to protect authentication. Then I made a new component called `ProtectedRoute`. In this `ProtectedRoute` function I only catch properties that are thrown, but somehow I only get the state from `React-Context`, and the props I send are unreadable, when in `console.log()` it is `undefined`.

ProtectedRoute.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { withAuth } from './Context/AuthContext'

function ProtectedRoute(props) {

    const {component: Component, ...rest} = props
    console.log(Component)
        return(
            props.isLoggedIn ? <Route {...rest} component={Component} /> : <Redirect push to="/" />
        )

    }

export default withAuth(ProtectedRoute)
```

App.js:

```
render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <AuthContextProvider>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                            <ProtectedRoute path="/portal" component={Main} />
                        </Switch>
                </AuthContextProvider>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
```

I have imported all required component btw, but if I change `ProtectedRoute` to normal `<Route>` by `react-router`, it can render component `Main`.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Please try `return <Route {...rest} render={props => props.isLoggedIn ? <Component {..props}/> : <Redirect push to="/"/>} />`

Comment: Hi, thanks for yor reply.
it gives the Maximum update depth exceeded error. even though I didn't do any looping. the problem is actually the parameter cannot be captured by the ProtectedRoute function. I tried console.log () and only got the state of react-context. no props are thrown from App.js like paths and components

Comment: This is my props contents when i console.log
`isLoggedIn: true
login: cridentials => {…}
logout: () => {…}
token: "myJWTtoken"
user:{myUserInfo}`

Comment: Could you please provide a working jsfiddle ?

Comment: The first comment by weedoze should work for you.